# Finding equation for exponential graph given only x intercept and asymptote

Tags: exponential-function, graphing-functions

I have been trying for ages now to find the equation for an exponential graph in the form $y=Ae^{Bx}+C$. I have been given the horizontal asymptote of $y =-2$ (which is C) and the point $(3\ln2, 0)$. I have tried trying to set up simultaneous equations and define A in terms of B but I'm really at a loss. I got quite close on one attempt but I feel like I could only get it if I was given one other point.

Answer (score 1):

After determining the asymptote of your exponential equation, you have two unknowns but only one equation. Your system of equations is thus underdetermined and has infinitely many solutions. For example, the graphs of $4\cdot2^{-x}-2$ and $8\cdot2^{-2x}-2$ have their horizontal asymptote at $y=-2$ and pass through $(1,0)$, but are different.

To find a specific solution you need to fix one of the unknowns arbitrarily and solve for the other. In this case, we know that $0=Ae^{3B\ln2}-2$, or $2=A8^B$. If we set $A=1$ we find that $B=\frac13$; if we set $B=1$ we find that $A=\frac14$. Hence $y=e^{\frac x3}-2$ and $y=\frac14e^x-2$ are possible equations for the graph.

If you had been given one more point on the graph as you wished, like the $y$-intercept, you would be able to find a unique equation.